# Help with hairy ball theorem, a question of orientation

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading a proof of the hairy ball theorem. The proof uses the fact that in the antipodal map, where $\underline r \mapsto \underline r'=-\underline r$, a differential form $\omega$ on the surface of an even dimensional sphere will transform as$\int \omega \mapsto -\int \omega$. I am trying to understand this with a concrete example where

$\omega = f\left ( \underline r \right )d \theta \wedge d \phi$

I believe the transformation to get the antipodal point is

$\theta \mapsto  \theta'=-\theta$,  $\phi \mapsto  \phi'=\phi+\pi$

which gives $d\theta \mapsto  d\theta'=-d\theta$ and $d\phi \mapsto  d\phi'=d\phi$

And so we get

$\int \omega'=\int f\left ( \underline r' \right )d\theta'd\phi'=\int f\left ( -\underline r \right )\left ( -d\theta \right )d\phi=-\int f\left ( -\underline r \right ) d\theta d\phi$

The trouble I am having is that the $f\left ( -\underline r  \right )$ is obviously not equal to $f\left ( \underline r  \right )$. So the right hand side of the expression above does not quite take the form of $-\int \omega$. So I don't quite end up with:

$\int \omega' = -\int \omega$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The "negation" of the integral doesn't happen "at the level of forms", only after you integrate. (Alternatively, pick a differential form for which $f(-r) = f(r)$, e.g., so that $\omega$ is the round area form.)